# Windows batch command to ignore some file lines?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cvs

I am redirecting the output of a cvs diff onto a log.txt file.

```
C:\Temp> cvs diff -b -B -r 1.5 -r 1.6 Project\src\Sample.java > log.txt
```

The generated content of the `log.txt` file upon executing the above command is like this :

```
Index: project/src/Sample.java
===================================================================
RCS file: \repobase/src/Sample.java,v
retrieving revision 1.5
retrieving revision 1.6
diff -r1.5 -r1.6
78a79,82
>       public java.lang.Class getJavaClass() {
>           return Sample.class;
>       }
> 
92c96
<           return Demo.getparentClass(this.getClass());
---
>           return MyClass.clazz;
```

All lines of this file that start with `<` or `>` are not necessary. I want to ignore all such lines only to push in the minimal rest into the `log.txt` file. How can I do this via windows command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the cvs diff --brief option will give you what you want.

If not, then you can pipe the diff output to FINDSDTR and let it filter the lines

```
cvs diff -b -B -r 1.5 -r 1.6 Project\src\Sample.java | findstr /vbl "< >" > log.txt
```

/v option means print lines that don't contain any of the strings

/b option means match the search string starting at the beginning of each line

/l means literal search string (as opposed to a regular expression)

Search string is split at each space, so "< >" is really 2 search strings.

For more more help on FINDSTR use `FINDSTR /?'.

For additional help see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053)